# AWS braket python sdk: user is not authorized to perform on quantum device

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ami, quantum-computing, qiskit

I have installed boto3, aws cli, and python-braket-sdk. I have run `aws configure`, and config with my IAM user. My IAM user isn't root user, but it has `AdministratorAccess`, `AmazonBraketFullAccess`, `AmazonBraketJobsExecutionPolicy` policies.

But if I tried to get some quantum device by this command:`aws braket get-device --device-arn arn:aws:braket:::device/qpu/ionq/ionQdevice`, it always return this error:

`An error occurred (AccessDeniedException) when calling the GetDevice operation: User: arn:aws:iam::178363055402:user/hblab-rnd is not authorized to perform: braket:GetDevice on resource: arn:aws:braket::178363055402:device/qpu/ionq/ionQdevice with an explicit deny`

If I run same below python from this link: https://github.com/aws/amazon-braket-sdk-python#usage, it also return similar error:

```
import boto3
from braket.aws import AwsDevice
from braket.circuits import Circuit
device = AwsDevice("arn:aws:braket:::device/quantum-simulator/amazon/sv1")
bell = Circuit().h(0).cnot(0, 1)
task = device.run(bell, shots=100)
print(task.result().measurement_counts)
```

Error output:

```
AccessDeniedException: An error occurred (AccessDeniedException) when calling the GetDevice 
operation: User: arn:aws:iam::178363055402:user/hblab-rnd is not authorized to perform: 
braket:GetDevice on resource: arn:aws:braket::178363055402:device/quantum-simulator/amazon/sv1 
with an explicit deny
```

I have already added permissions for Braket, but I can not figure the reason for this bug. Please help

**System information**

- **aws cli**: aws-cli/2.7.11 Python/3.9.11 Windows/10 exe/AMD64 prompt/off
- **Amazon Braket Python SDK version**: 1.25.2
- **Amazon Braket schemas**: 1.10.0
- **Amazon Braket default simulator**: 1.6.2
- **Python version**: 3.8.13

Comment: *Something* is denying the action, either an attached policy, a SCP, a permission boundary or a resources policy.

Comment: @luk2302 when I tried to run this command with my root account, everything is fine. I don't know what is problem with IAM account. So I need to re-check everything about permission in my project ?

Comment: Not that difficult and complex but yes, go the IAM console and check all the things I mentioned. If braket has resource policies check them as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer. I have activated MFA authorization on my account, but in my `aws cli`, I don't setup it. So I need to setup my `aws cli` by a new account without MFA, or set up MFA for my `aws cli`. Thank you everyone for help